# How to replace center (third) break/stop lamp/bulb in Ford Galaxy 2009

Tags: ford, brake-light, bulbs, galaxy

I removed the plastic cover, but didn't find any way to pull out the light structure. No screws, no direct access...
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site! :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documentation for this, but did find a video.

The video shows the assembly having press clips that need to be pushed out. Unsure what language this is, but the watching should help you. Seems simple enough.

https://youtu.be/hAhSiLdGf7E